# Remove participants from data frame based off multiple column filters in R using inbuilt methods

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
ID     Gene     Tier     Consequence   
1314   ABC      TIER1    missense  
1314   PKD1     TIER1    frameshift  
6245   BJD      TIER1    splice_site_variant 
1314   ADAMST   TIER3    stop_gain
7631   PKD2     TIER1    missense
7631   BFH      TIER2    stop_gain
5336   PKD1     TIER3    missense
1399   PKD1     TIER2    non-coding
```

I want to subset the table so that if the conditions are met all rows with the relevant ID are removed.

If there is a line where the gene PKD1 or PKD2 are present AND the tier is TIER1 OR a "missense" appears in the consequence section of a line where PKD1 or PKD2 are the genes I would like to remove all instances of the corresponding ID. I.E the resulting table should look like:

```
ID     Gene     Tier     Consequence    
6245   BJD      TIER1    splice_site_variant 
1399   PKD1     TIER2    non-coding
```

I work in an airlock on a HPC using R so getting R tools in and out is tricky (dplyr etc) so a solution using inbuilt R tools would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: @A.S.K. that would be because I'm an idiot and didn't give you a good example. I've updated it to be a little clearer sorry! I added ID 1399 which whilst has PKD1 it is TIER2 and not a missense so wouldn't get filtered. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version with just base R.  It uses a loop, so if you have a really large dataset, you might need something vectorized for efficiency.

```
for(current.id in unique(df$ID)) {
    if(nrow(df[df$ID == current.id &
               df$Gene %in% c("PKD1", "PKD2") &
               (df$Tier == "TIER1" |
                df$Consequence == "missense"),]) > 0) {
        df = df[df$ID != current.id,]
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @A.S.K this worked nicely. I now need to try and understand what's going on! Doe the 3rd line "df$Gene %in% c("PKD1, "PKD2") mean PKD1 OR PKD2? Why do you need a >0 after missense?

Comment: Exactly; the `%in%` is just a shortcut for "equals anything in the vector".  The `>0` is because the `if` condition asks "how many problematic rows does the dataframe have for this ID?"  (That's the `nrow` part.)  If the answer is "more than 0", we've found an ID we need to eliminate.

Answer (score 1):

An option is after grouping by 'ID', check for 'Gene' that have values 'PKD1', 'PKD2', and (`&`) the value of 'Tier' is 'TIER1' or `(`|`), the`lag`or`lead` values of 'Consequence' is "missense" and if there are none, then return the 'ID'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(!any(Gene %in% c("PKD1", "PKD2") & 
  (Tier == "TIER1"|
    (lag(Consequence, default = first(Consequence)) == "missense")|
      lead(Consequence, default = last(Consequence)) == "missense")))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
#    ID Gene  Tier  Consequence        
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>              
#1  6245 BJD   TIER1 splice_site_variant
#2  1399 PKD1  TIER2 non-coding
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1314L, 1314L, 6245L, 1314L, 7631L, 7631L, 
5336L, 1399L), Gene = c("ABC", "PKD1", "BJD", "ADAMST", "PKD2", 
"BFH", "PKD1", "PKD1"), Tier = c("TIER1", "TIER1", "TIER1", "TIER3", 
"TIER1", "TIER2", "TIER3", "TIER2"), Consequence = c("missense", 
"frameshift", "splice_site_variant", "stop_gain", "missense",
"stop_gain", "missense", "non-coding")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: thanks @akrun for the help! I will try and get dplyr into the environment and give it a go